# Boostrap alinhamento Vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

estou fazendo uma grid em boostrap, e não consigo deixar corretamente alinhado verticalmente.

Deveria ficar sempre assim:

```
*-------------*     *--------------*    *--------------*
| card grande |     | card Pequeno |    | card Pequeno |
*-------------*     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |     |     dois     |    |     quatro   |
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|     UM      |
|             |
|             |
|             |
|             |  
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |     | card Pequeno |    | card Pequeno |
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |     |     tres     |    |     cinco    |
*-------------*     *--------------*    *--------------*
```

Veja que os cards tres e cinco, deveriam estar alinhados com a base do card um, porém eles estão ficando assim:

```
*-------------*     *--------------*    *--------------*
| card grande |     | card Pequeno |    | card Pequeno |
*-------------*     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |     |     dois     |    |     quatro   |
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|     UM      |  
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |     | card Pequeno |    | card Pequeno |
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |     |     tres     |    |     cinco    |
|             |     *--------------*    *--------------*
|             |
|             | 
|             |
*-------------*
```

como os card tres e cinco, logo abaixo dos dois e quatro.

[Aqui esta um exemplo de como estou fazendo agora](https://jsfiddle.net/alexandrequeiroz/8ap7tmnv/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara nem precisa de CSS além das classes nativas do Bootstrap. Vc pode usar as classes `Flex` do *framework* para ajustar isso. Consulte aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Repare que primeiro vc precisa colocar a `.row` com 100% de altura do pai, para isso use a classe `h-100`, depois vc alinha os filhos da parte de baixo com `align-self-end` para eles ficarem na base da `col`

Veja como fica

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6">
            a
            <br />

            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            final
        </div>

        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col-6">
                    b
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    c
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                    d
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 align-self-end">
                    e
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[Código Funcioando.](https://jsfiddle.net/hqwtaroy/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.
vou marcar como respondido.

Comment: @AlexandreQueiroz legal que deu certo ai. A boa prática já que vc está usando o Framework é que vc Realmente use as classes nativas dele, evite jeitinhos com CSS customizados, pois isso pode te trazer problemas no futuro, principalmente com o grid e a responsividade... Boa sorte ai!

Comment: @AlexandreQueiroz Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como aceita nesse `✔` ai ao lado esquerdo perto das setinhas. Basta clicar nele e a pergunta fica marcada como resolvida e com resposta aceita :)

Answer (score 2):

Uma sugestao:

```
<div class="container bottom-align-div">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            d
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            e
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottom-align-div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  }
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/x0ko7tmq/

Comment: Aqui não funcionou seu código, o position : absolut; quebra o sistema de colunas.

Comment: coloquei no fiddle. O trecho que voce postou pra mim funcionou... será q outra parte do seu codigo está sendo afetado ou interferindo?

Comment: não foi eu que fez a pergunta hahah, mas eu fiz um teste aqui e não deu, vou tentar novamente

Comment: Achei a diferença do seu código pro meu, é q você colocou a class container. funcionou.

Comment: hahahah foi mal nao tinha visto que nao era o autor ;)

Comment: funciona parcialmente, quando voce ter varias colunas o Position Absolute acaba dando problemas.